# Iterate over a JSON response from API in Powershell

Tags: json, powershell

It's kinda tricky because the API response is supposed to be in JSON format, however, if I try to access a property it returns null

```
PS C:\Users\bryanar> $response.ClientASN
```

Then I checked the type of the response

```
PS C:\Users\bryanar> $response.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                                                                                              
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                                                                                              
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

If I try to approach to the object in a different way I even get the error that's supposed to mean that the variable is not a JSON object

```
At line:1 char:20
+ $response| ConvertFrom-Json | Select ClientASN
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromJsonCommand
```

So I tell PowerShell to do so but even then I get a null value

```
$response= Invoke-RestMethod `
    -Uri "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/$zoneID/logs/received?start=$startDate&end=$endDate&fields=$fields" `
    -Method GET `
    -Headers $header `
    -ContentType 'application/json; charset=utf-8' | ConvertTo-Json

PS C:\Users\bryanar> $response| ConvertFrom-Json | Select ClientASN

ClientASN
---------
```

This is what `$response` shows when I print it in the console

```
{"ClientASN": 8075,"ClientCountry": "us","ClientIP": "0.0.0.0"}
{"ClientASN": 7545,"ClientCountry": "au","ClientIP": "0.0.0.0"}
{"ClientASN": 8075,"ClientCountry": "us","ClientIP": "0.0.0.0"}
{"ClientASN": 7545,"ClientCountry": "au","ClientIP": "0.0.0.0"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding some Parentheses works, not sure why. Something to do with processing the data before sending it to the `Select` pipe. Those more knowledgeable should be able to explain the very specific reason.

```
$JSON = @'
[{
        "ClientASN": 8075,
        "ClientCountry": "us",
        "ClientIP": "0.0.0.0"
    },
    {
        "ClientASN": 8075,
        "ClientCountry": "us",
        "ClientIP": "0.0.0.0"
    },
    {
        "ClientASN": 8075,
        "ClientCountry": "us",
        "ClientIP": "0.0.0.0"
    },
    {
        "ClientASN": 7545,
        "ClientCountry": "au",
        "ClientIP": "0.0.0.0"
    }
]
'@

($JSON | ConvertFrom-Json) | select ClientASN
```

Comment: Well that does the trick, but how can I convert the API response so I can have something like `$response = @'[$response']@`